# Divide dataframe rows if column name has certain attribute in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have three DataFrames: one containing a codification, one containing values and the third containing divisors.

I would like to divide the second dataframe by the third based on the columns codification, without looping through. How can I do it?

```
names=['Green','Blue','Red','Yellow']
values=numpy.random.randint(1,10,[3,4])
attributes=['Small','Small','Medium','Large']
attributes1=['Small','Medium','Large']    
divisors=numpy.random.randint(1,5,(3,3))

db=pandas.DataFrame(attributes,index=names)
df=pandas.DataFrame(values,columns=names)
df1=pandas.DataFrame(divisors,columns=attributes1)

values_divided=pandas.DataFrame(values,columns=names)

for name in values_divided.columns:
    values_divided[name]=df[name]/df1[db[0][name]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way:

```
# perform vectorised calculation
arr = df.values / df1.loc[:, df.columns.map(db[0].get)].values

# feed result into dataframe
res = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=df.columns)

print(res)

      Green      Blue       Red    Yellow
0  0.500000  3.000000  0.333333  1.666667
1  4.000000  3.500000  2.000000  2.500000
2  2.666667  1.333333  4.000000  8.000000
```

Comment: What if I have more names with the same attribute and so I don't have symmetrical matrices?

Comment: I have slightly changed the question, as your solution applied to this case raises an error: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Thanks again for your help

Comment: The desired output is the final dataframe resulting from the loop: Green/Small, Blue/Small, Red/Medium and Yellow/Large.

i would like to avoid looping